# Postgres password authentication issue

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I've installed PostgreSQL 9.1 and pgadmin3 on Ubuntu Server 13.10.

I configured postgresql.conf with: `listen_addresses = '*'`

also I configured ph_hba.conf by changed peer connections to `md5`

Plus I reset the password of postgres by: `sudo password postgres`

then restarted the service with `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

after that I tried to connect to the default PostgreSQL template database:

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
```

but login failed with this error message:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

then I tried to login from the pgadmin, which gave me the same error.

I've read here that it might be a password expiry dates bug
[PostgreSQL user can not connect to server after changing password](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36137/postgresql-user-can-not-connect-to-server-after-changing-password)

but I couldn't solve it coz I cannot login with psql. Does anyone now how to resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

ph_hba file:

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
local   all             all                                     md5
local   all             all                                     trust

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
hostssl all             all             192.168.0.0/16          trust
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/16          trust

host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Can you try: sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -W template1

Comment: Gave me the same error message

Comment: You have changed the system user `postgres`'s password, but you haven't changed the DB user `postgres`'s password, which in case of `md5` authentication, is the important one. And also in this case you don't need to start `psql` under system user `postgres`. Please post your `pg_hba.conf` here if you still need help!

Comment: You cloned this post here: http://askubuntu.com/q/413585/75715 . Thanks for wasting everyone's time. My answer on that post explains what mistake caused this problem, and what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your pg_hba.conf, modify

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

then you'll be able to login without password

Comment: If you do this, I hope you trust everyone able to access the server the PostgreSQL instance is running on, because you just gave them total access to the PostgreSQL server. I strongly recommend at least using `peer` authentication.